# XMPP Smack4.2 Android IncomingListener remains issue

Tags: android, listener, message, smack

I'm trying Smack 4.2 on Android and I have a problem with the IncomingListener.

I created a class MyXMPP totaly dedicated to XMPP work.

( I just have one android activity. )

In this activity, in OnCreate(), I connected to XMPP server using my class MyXMPP and I retrieved my ChatManager in my a final value to place on an IncomingChatMessageListener().

Everything works well in the first try. But when I pause my activity and relaunch  it, it's like the older listener remains. So at this moment, I receive messages in double.

If I pause again my application, it's like I have 3 listeners and so on.

I precise I have no problem whith connection to my server.

Here my code :

Android activity :

```
public class TestMessagingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_messaging);

        MyXMPPP.getInstance().init("test", "test");
        MyXMPPP.getInstance().connect();
        final ChatManager chatManager = MyXMPPP.getInstance().getChatManager();
        chatManager.addIncomingListener(new IncomingChatMessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void newIncomingMessage(EntityBareJid from, Message message, Chat chat) {
                final AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void> mReceiveMessage = new AsyncTask<Message, Void, Void>() {
                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground(Message... params) {

                        ChatMessage chatMessage = new ChatMessage(params[0].getBody(), false);
                        Log.v("TAG", "index=message arrived");
                        Log.v("TAG", params[0].getBody());

                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Void res) {

                    }


                };
                mReceiveMessage.execute(message);
            }
        });
}
}
```

MyXMPP class :

```
public class MyXMPPP {

    private static final String DOMAIN = "test.com";

    private AbstractXMPPConnection connection;
    private XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener();
    private ChatManager chatManager;
    private Presence presence;

    boolean isConnected=false;
    boolean chatManagerCreated=false;

    private static MyXMPPP instance =null;

    public synchronized static MyXMPPP getInstance() {
        if(instance==null){
            instance = new MyXMPPP();
        }
        return instance;
    }


    public void init(String user, String password)  {

        XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder configBuilder = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();
        configBuilder.setUsernameAndPassword(user, password);
        configBuilder.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.required);
        configBuilder.setKeystoreType(null);
        try {
            configBuilder.setXmppDomain(DOMAIN);
        } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(configBuilder.build());
        connection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);

    }

    public void connect() {
        if (isConnected == false) {

            AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> connectionThread = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    try {
                        connection.connect();
                        connection.login();
                    } catch (SmackException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (XMPPException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return null;
                }
            };
            connectionThread.execute();
        }
    }


    public AbstractXMPPConnection getConnection() {
        return connection;
    }

    public void createChatManager()
    {
        if(chatManagerCreated==false)
        {
            chatManager=ChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
            chatManagerCreated=true;
            Log.v("TAG", "index=chat manager created");
}
    }

    public ChatManager getChatManager()
    {
        return chatManager;
    }


    public void sendMessage(String message, EntityBareJid jid)
    {
        if(chatManagerCreated==true)
        {
            Chat chat = chatManager.chatWith(jid);
            try {
                chat.send(message);
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    public boolean getIsConnected(){
        return isConnected;
    }



    public class XMPPConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener{

        @Override
        public void connected(XMPPConnection connection) {

        }

        @Override
        public void authenticated(XMPPConnection connection, boolean resumed) {

            isConnected=true;

            createChatManager();

            presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available, "Online", 24, Presence.Mode.available);
            try {
                connection.sendStanza(presence);
            } catch (SmackException.NotConnectedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosed() {
            isConnected=false;
        }

        @Override
        public void connectionClosedOnError(Exception e) {
            isConnected=false;
        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionSuccessful() {

        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectingIn(int seconds) {

        }

        @Override
        public void reconnectionFailed(Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Is this problem normal ?

When I put the listener to on the chatManager in the XMPP class, I don't have this problem. But I would like to do work in my activity / in my view, so having the listener here seems to be better.

I need some advice.
Thank you.

Nico.